# Retrieving ROWID from SqLite database using EF

Tags: c#, sqlite, rowid

How can I retrieve ROWID value from EF DBSet object:
I would like to do something like below:

```
var accounts = _context.Accounts.Include(x => x.UserFunctions);
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
            int rowid = account.GetRowId();
}
```

where `Accounts` is defined in the context like this:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<Account>
{

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

and `Account` is defined like:

```
public class Account : IdentityUser
{ 
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way of doing account.GetRowId()?

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the unique Id for the inserted row
By(as per your example)

```
Int rowId=account.Id;
```

To achieve more control over your code, you can do,

```
public class Account : IdentityUser
{ 
    [Key]  //you can also add options i.e: DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    Public int RowId{get;set;} //also you can fully manually handle it here however you want
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But the `account.Id` is a long string as the Account is  derived from  `IdentityUser` - so that will not work

Comment: So, if you want to have more control over it, I suggest, declare an int Id object into your model and put [key] annotation over it


then, in the annotation by adding your own conditions you can modify its format as well as type

Comment: Would you be able to provide me some example or link to example

Comment: I am editing my answer.

Comment: I did that and my `RowId` is zero in every row. Do I need to do something else in addition to what you suggested?

Comment: Also when I open SQLite database browser only Id (coming from from `IdentityUser`) is marked as a primary key. `RowId` is marked as an ordinary column - I thought that annotation [key] would make it part of primary key

Comment: In that case, remove [Key] and you can use 

Yes, you can use the following attribute:
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It now throws exception `SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: AspNetUsers.RowId'`

Comment: I will try doing a sample code similar to your scenerio by tomorrow. Hopefully